# Cover old ugly floor in a rented apartment?

Tags: flooring, floor, rental, cover

We have to move to an old rented apartment, the floor looks terrible (it's green! and that's the original color!!). How can I hide the shame? I'm looking for the **cheapest** solution possible (ANYTHING would be better than that rotten floor), that can be taken off when we (happily) leave the place without damaging the original floor?

p.s. It should also be safe to our health, e.g. I've heard some opinions that PVC is not too healthy inside a house?

Comment: What is the existing floor (carpet, vinyl, tile, ...)? Is it a rectangular shape or something non-standard? How big? Are you trying to avoid seams? Is it a high-traffic area? Is carpet okay or is this eg, a kitchen where carpet would get dirty? Are there any doors that open over top of this floor that would limit the height of what you can put on top?

Comment: @gregmac - The existing floor is stone tile, rectangular shape, about 1.5 feet, I don't care about seams. Carpet might be okay, the question if it's the best option, it's the entire house (including kitchen), there are doors over that floor (actually it's a good point which I've never thought of..)

Answer (score 2):

You can't alter anything about an apartment without permission of the landlord. With their permission, the answer is: anything! Without it, the answer is: nothing.

Comment: Aside from area rugs and runners, exactly the above. It's a discussion to be had with the Landlord. Back when we rented, we always looked for landlords that would allow reasonable maintenance that with prior consultation and permission, could be deducted from the rent. **Skilled** DIY can be appreciated.